# How do I find everything beside regex in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to find and mark all the code that doesn't fit my regex.

```
[^\}]*navbar[^\{]*\{[^\}]*[\}\s]*
```

Basically I want to mark everything beside red-highlighted part

[my-regex-at-work.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgNkL.jpg)

The code:

```
.pull-right>.dropdown-menu {
    right: 0;
    left: auto
}

.dropup .caret,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .caret {
    content: "";
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px dashed;
    border-bottom: 4px solid\9
}

.dropup .dropdown-menu,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2px
    bottom: 100%;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
        right: 0;
        left: auto
    }
    .navbar-right .dropdown-menu-left {
        right: auto;
        left: 0
    }
}

.btn-group,
.btn-group-vertical {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

My ideas do not work

```
[^[^\}]*navbar[^\{]*\{[^\}]*[\}\s]*]
[^[[^\}]*navbar[^\{]*\{[^\}]*[\}\s]*]]
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be not possible with notepad++ because of backtracking, it could be done if regex engine supports control verbs:

```
[^\}]*navbar[^\{]*\{[^\}]*[\}\s]*(*SKIP)(?!)|.*
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/l5QH1S/2)

to tell to the engine to skip the matched part and fail, otherwise when engine fails to match it continues with input cursor on next character.

Comment: Jesus... it seems like I have to learn some programming language now. Would python support your regex?

Comment: You can also generate regexes on regex101.com and just execute it afterwards. But Python wouldn't support this regex as you see if you're clicking on python in his saved regex! PHP or Perl would support it!

Comment: at regex101 I have encountered "catastrophic backtracking" so far... a catastrophe indeed.

Comment: I've got no idea what you're talking about. This regex works, at least in PHP/PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

Append `\K|.*` to your regex:

```
[^\}]*navbar[^\{]*\{[^\}]*[\}\s]*\K|.*
```

Then hit *Mark All* button.

Comment: Notepad++ regex engine (Boost) doesn't support [backtracking control verbs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html).